# simple inequality for vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

For vectors x,y $\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ with entries ordered decreasingly: if
$$
\sum_{i=1}^kx_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^ky_i \ \forall 1\leq k\leq n
$$
then $\|x\|_p\leq\|y\|_p$.

From https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2819688/780264

Comment: What $p$ are you working in? Are you familiar with [Minkowski inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/holders-inequality/#minkowskis-inequality)?

Comment: p is a real number between 1 and infinity. I am familiar with the Minkowski inequality

Comment: How about majorization on convex functions?

Comment: I've just looked this up for the first time. I'm not familiar with it but I understand that the fact that every symmetric, convex function is Schur convex would suffice here. I'm missing some theory for this though.

Answer (score 0):

This result is a consequence of *Corollary II.3.4* of the same reference in the linked (Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*). Here is an adaptation of the proof given in the text.

I will use $x \prec_w y$ to mean that when $x,y$ are reindexed in decreasing order, $\sum_{i=1}^kx_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^ky_i$ for $1\leq k\leq n$. $x \prec y$ denotes the same with the additional condition that $\sum_{i=1}^kx_i = \sum_{i=1}^ky_i$. I will use $x \leq y$ to mean that $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i$. We will first prove the following:

> **Claim:** If $x,y \in \Bbb R_+^n$ satisfy $x\prec y$, then $x^p \prec_w y^p$ (where $(x_1,\dots,x_n)^p = (x_1^p,\dots,x_n^p)$).

We need the following facts:

1. The function $f(x) = x^p$ is convex over $\Bbb R_+$ for $p \geq 1$
2. If $x \leq y$, then $\|x\|_p \leq \|y\|_p$
3. If $x \prec y$, then there exists a doubly stochastic matrix $A$ (i.e. the row and column sums of $A$ are all $1$) for which $x = Ay$ (cf. Bhatia Theorem II.1.10)
4. The [Birkhoff von-Neumann theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) such a matrix $A$ can be written in the form $\sum_j P_j$ for permutation matrices $P_j$ and positive $t_j$ with $\sum_j t_j = 1$.

With that, the proof proceeds as follows. We have
$$
x^p = [Ay]^p = \left[\sum_j t_j P_j y \right]^p \leq 
\sum_j t_j (P_j y)^p
= \sum_j t_j P_j(y)^p = A y^p
$$
So, we have $x^p \leq Ay^p$ and $Ay^p \prec y^p$. It follows that $x^p \prec_w y^p$.

From the fact that $x^p \prec_w y^p$, it follows that the sum of the entries of $x^p$ is less than that of $y^p$, from which it follows that $\|x\|_p \leq \|y\|_p$.

It now remains to be shown that $x \prec_w y \implies \|x\|_p \leq \|y\|_p$. To that end, it suffices to note that if $x \prec_w y$, there exists a vector $u$ (ordered decreasingly) for which
$$
x \leq u \prec y,
$$
(cf. Bhatia Theorem II.2.8, a consequence of fact 3). It follows that $\|x\|_p \leq \|u\|_p \leq \|y\|_p$ .