# Why does $\rho'=\sum_i p_i U_i \rho U_i^\dagger$ with $U_i$ unitary imply $\rho'\preceq \rho$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, unitary-matrices

Let $\rho$ be an Hermitian matrix with unit trace (this is the context I've found this result stated in, but I don't know if these restrictions are necessary for the result).
Suppose $p_i\ge0$ with $\sum_i p_i=1$, and let $U_i$ be unitaries.
Consider
$$\rho'= \sum_i p_i \, U_i \rho U_i^\dagger.$$
Then $\rho'\preceq \rho$, by which I mean that the vector of eigenvalues of $\rho'$ is [majorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) by that of $\rho$.
I think this is shown in the reference "*A. Uhlmann, Wiss. Z. Karl-Marx-Univ. Leipzig 20, 633 (1971)*" but I could not find an English version of it.

For $p_i=\delta_{i0}$ the result is clear, as $U\rho U^\dagger$ has the same eigenvalues of $\rho$. How do you prove the general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the following result: for a size $n$ Hermitian matrix $A$, let
$$
\lambda_1(A) \geq \lambda_2(A) \geq\cdots \geq \lambda_n(A)
$$
denote the eigenvalues of $A$. For symmetric matrices $A_1,\dots, A_m$, we have
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j\left(\sum_{p=1}^m A_p \right) \leq
\sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{p=1}^m \lambda_j(A_p).
$$
This in turn can be seen as a consequence of the fact that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j(A) = \max_{U \in \Bbb C^{n\times k}, U^\dagger U = I} \operatorname{tr}(U^\dagger A U).
$$

---

Explanation of the inequality: note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j\left(\sum_{p=1}^m A_p \right) &= 
\max\left\{\operatorname{tr}\left[U\left(\sum_{p=1}^m A_p \right)U^\dagger \right]: U \in \Bbb C^{n\times k}, U^\dagger U = I\right\}
\\ & = 
\max\left\{\sum_{p=1}^m \operatorname{tr}\left[UA_pU^\dagger\right] : U \in \Bbb C^{n\times k}, U^\dagger U = I\right\}
\\ & \leq
\max\left\{\sum_{p=1}^m \operatorname{tr}\left[U_pA_pU_p^\dagger\right] : U_p \in \Bbb C^{n\times k}, U_p^\dagger U_p = I \text{ for } p = 1,\dots,m \right\}
\end{align}

Comment: thanks. About the last relation, aren't you effectively just computing $\max_P \operatorname{tr}(AP)$ maximising over trace-$k$ projections $P$ (with the relation following from some variation of the minmax theorem I guess)? Is there a reason to write it as a maximisation over unitaries this way?

Comment: you are also using I think, to go from the third to the second equation, the relation $\lambda_j(UA_p U^\dagger)\le \lambda_j(A_p)$ with $U^\dagger U=I$. Where does this come from?

Comment: @glS Yes it's equivalent; note that $$
\operatorname{tr}(U^\dagger AU) = \operatorname{tr}(A[UU^\dagger]).
$$ 
There is no particular reason to write it one way or the other, but this is the form I learned first.

Comment: @glS Your second comment is not correct. See my latest edit for clarification.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. Are you possibly missing a few traces in the last equation? Shoud be $\max$ of $\operatorname{tr}$

Comment: @glS Yes, that's a typo

Answer (score 2):

For any Hermitian matrix $A$, let $c>0$ be any sufficiently large number. Then $A+cI$ is positive semidefinite and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda^\downarrow_i(A)
=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda^\downarrow_i(A+cI)-kc
=\|A+cI\|_k-kc,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_k$ here denotes the Ky Fan $k$-norm (the sum of the largest $k$ singular values) of a matrix. The inequality $\rho'\preceq\rho$ now follows directly from the triangle inequality for Ky Fan $k$-norm.

*Remark.* [Ky Fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky_Fan) was an ethnic Chinese mathematician whose first name was Ky and whose last name is Fan. As it is customary to use only the surname when we name something after a mathematician, the norm is more appropriately called *Fan $k$-norm* rather than *Ky Fan $k$-norm*. However, what has become convention is hard to change. I will keep using the term "Ky Fan $k$-norm" in future.

Comment: nice method. A related question on the Ky Fan norm is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28352/173147 (linking it here for my own future benefit)

Answer (score 0):

This is a reformulation of the information provided by the other [great](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3756449/173147) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3756427/173147).

The question relates to the eigenvalues of $\rho'\equiv \sum_{k=1}^m p_k U_k \rho U_k^\dagger$.
Consider the matrices $A_k=p_k U_k \rho U_k^\dagger$. Being $U_k$ unitary, $\rho$ Hermitian, and $p_k\ge0$, it follows that $A_k$ are hermitian.

Denote with $\lambda_k^\downarrow(A)$ the $k$-th largest eigenvalue of $A$.
The relation $\rho'\preceq\rho$ means, explicitly, that
$$\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j^\downarrow\bigg(\underbrace{\sum_{p=1}^m A_p}_{\equiv\rho'} \bigg)\le \sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_j^\downarrow(\rho),\qquad k=1,..,m.$$

It is a general result that, given Hermitian matrices $A_p$, and denoting with $\|A\|_k$ the sum of the $k$ largest eigenvalues of $A$ (this is also referred to as the *Ky Fan norm* of $A$), we have
$\|\sum_p A_p\|_k\le \sum_p \|A_p\|_k$. This is shown *e.g.* [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/28354/173147).

In our specific case, we thus have
$$\|\rho'\|_k = \bigg\|\sum_{\ell=1}^m A_\ell\bigg\|_k
\le \sum_{\ell=1}^m \|A_\ell\|_k
= \sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{\ell=1}^m \lambda_j^\downarrow(A_\ell).$$

From the definition of $A_p$, we also have that
$\lambda_j^\downarrow(A_\ell)=p_\ell \lambda_j^\downarrow(\rho)$,
and thus, because $\sum_\ell p_\ell=1$,
$$\|\rho'\|_k \le \sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_j^\downarrow(\rho) = \|\rho\|_k.$$